# C++ list::sort of classes by members

Tags: c++, list, sorting, categories, member

How can I sort a list of classes by a certain member variable?

```
class Klasse {
  int _a;
  int _b;

}

...
list<Klasse> liste;
liste.sort();   // sorts by _a
liste.sort(?);  // how to sort by _b now?
```

Comment: Have you tried [creating a custom comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508496/comparators-in-stl)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a [comparator object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). Here's an example using a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

```
std::list<Klasse> liste;
liste.sort([](Klasse const & lhs, Klasse const & rhs) {
    return lhs._b < rhs._b;
});
```

Comment: C++11 or later? These things are great if your compiler supports them.

Comment: that's pretty C+11 :) nice!

Comment: By the way, lambda is not something that someone new to C++ will easily understand, so this might not be the best answer without further references.

Answer (score 3):

[See the reference.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort)

You can write a comparison function - basically anything that can be called with two arguments of the element type of your list, and this call returns value convertible to `bool`. Such "anything" can be a lambda, function object, or simply just a function:

```
bool klasse_sort_by_b(const Klasse& l, const Klasse& r)
{
    return l._b < r._b;
}

liste.sort(klasse_sort_by_b);
```

Answer (score 1):

you need this implementation of sort:

```
template<typename Compare>    
void sort (Compare comp);
```

then pass inside a compare function like:

```
bool compareByA( const Klasse& first, const Klasse& second ){
 return first._a < second._a;
}
```

then call it:

```
std::list<Klasse> lst;
...
lst.sort(compareByA);
lst.sort(compareByB);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/

You should write your own comparer, example and usage in the link ;)

here is the code example as promised

(thanks for the constructive criticism)

```
 bool compare_by_b (const Klasse& first, const Klasse& second)
    {
      return first._b < second._b ;
    }

 liste.sort(compare_by_b);
```

Comment: You should include code in your answer instead of linking to external resources.

Comment: he answers the question (though shortly), and gives a reference. Possibly not the most thorough explanation, but worth more than a downvote!

Comment: @MarcusMüller: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I agree, but he did *not* just link somewhere. He said "write a comparer", which is absolutely true and might even be enough to give OP a start, if the linked site went down at one point.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, and all you have to do is implement a comparator class, or overload the comparison `Klasse::operator<` operators. For reference on the `sort` method, see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/).