# Returning a class object based on two variables C++

Tags: c++, class

I need help with a problem pertaining to classes. I know how to solve it but I am wondering if there is a better solution than my current idea.

Each **`Class Tile Object`** and **`Class Player Object`** has an **x** and **y** position. I would like to know if there is a way to expedite things. My current idea is `if-else` statements like this:

```
if(x==1) {
    if(y==1) {

       return tileone1;

    } else if(y==2) {  

       return tileone2;

    } else if(y==3) {  

       return tileone3;

    } else if(y==4) {  

       return tileone4;

    } else if(y==5) {  

       return tileone5;

    } //......

} else if(x==2) { 
      if(y==1) {

       return tiletwo1;

    } else if(y==2) {  

       return tiletwo2;

    } else if(y==3) {  

       return tiletwo3;

    } else if(y==4) {  

       return tiletwo4;

    } else if(y==5) {  

       return tiletwo5;

    } //......
} //......
```

The problem is it would take way too long to write this for every tile.

**I need a function that will return a Tile object based on the x and y input of the `Object Player`. Any other solution would be great as well.**

```
Tile getTileBasedOnCoords(int x, int y){

}
```

Comment: Perhaps code that is indented correctly and can compile might be a good start

Comment: @EdHeal the code isn't important, It's just an example.

Comment: If "the code" isn't important, you might want to reconsider your choice of a career. Because "the code" is very important in computer science.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Sorry, I meant that the code that I displayed was not very important to my question, I was just meant to aid the explanation of my question that I had.

Comment: @CarterCall So you didn't store all of your Tiles in some kind of a container?  Not even a simple array of Tiles?  This is the information that you left out, code or no code.

Comment: What are the range of x, y ? Could you create a matrix of Tile ? Can several Tile may have same position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The easiest seems to be (given the question) is by putting all Tile objects into the array, and returning the one with corresponding index.

Comment: That sounds great. I don't have any experience with vectors so if you could supply me with an example page or explain yourself that would help a lot.

Comment: @Even though it sounds great, you don't even need vectors for this.  An array of Tiles still would work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, good point, as the size of the array has to be known at compile time.

Comment: @SergeyA is there anyway to make an array index number be negative? This is just so I can have a center point. If not, I can live without it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map with custom keys providing x and y values. This way you have direct access to the tile without the need to compare each tile with the player position (see `getSectorByCoordinate()` in the following code taken from a project of mine).

```
struct CSectorCoordinate
{
  private:
    int mX;
    int mY;

  public:
    CSectorCoordinate();
    CSectorCoordinate(int aX, int aY);

    bool operator() (const CSectorCoordinate & a, const CSectorCoordinate & b) const;

    int getX();
    int getY();
};

...

bool CSectorCoordinate::operator() (const CSectorCoordinate & a, const CSectorCoordinate & b) const
{
  // note: the following conditions ensure a strict weak ordering (see documentation of std::map)
  if (a.mX < b.mX)
    return true;

  if (b.mX < a.mX)
    return false;

  return a.mY < b.mY;
}

...

typedef std::map<CSectorCoordinate, Configuration::CSectorEntity *, CSectorCoordinate> CSectorCoordinateMap;

CSectorCoordinateMap mSectorCoordinateMap;

...

bool CSectorEntityConfigurationBunch::getSectorByCoordinate(int aX, int aY, Configuration::CSectorEntity * & prSector)
{
  CSectorCoordinateMap::const_iterator i(mSectorCoordinateMap.find(CSectorCoordinate(aX, aY)));

  if (i != mSectorCoordinateMap.end())
    prSector = i->second;
  else
    prSector = 0;

  return prSector;
}
```

Comment: How would I do this? Sorry, I'm pretty new at programming and c++.

Comment: @CarterCall See my edit, i posted some code, feel free to ask when something is unclear.

Comment: What a terrible idea to use a key type as a comparator.

Comment: @SergeyA because of?

Comment: Because a key is a key, and a comparator is a comparator. They have different responsibilities and should not be mixed.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy It's not a fact which can be proven. A link isn't helpful. What SergyA is saying is that the key and the comparator are different concepts. One performs operations on the other. It doesn't make sense to use one key to compare two completely separate keys. That's not a model that makes any real-world sense.

Comment: @JordanMelo True but i still doubt that the implementation would be much nicer when seperating these 2 concepts here. My code is based on the following sentence from the std::map docs and i think it's ok as is: `The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this type and a and b are key values, shall return true if a is considered to go before b in the strict weak ordering the function defines.`

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy: It would make more sense to have `bool operator <(const CSectorCoordinate&lhs, const CSectorCoordinate& rhs)` (that you could implement `return std::tie(lhs.mX, lhs.mY) < std::tie(rhs.mX, rhs.mY)` btw)

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy The implementation would be much nicer because it would make logical sense. Just because it works doesn't mean you should roll with it. Your implementation would not pass a modest code review.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. Define `CSectorCoordinate::operator<` and then you don't even have to specify a comparator in the template parameters of `std::map`, as the default comparator type is `std::less<KeyType>`, which will invoke the `operator<` defined for your key type. Write idiomatic code and things will just work.

Comment: @JordanMelo I found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/183678/3936440) that supports the claim of SergeyA but it also states a style guide which is against the `operator<` approach. Therefore I consider my approach still as valid as it is one of the 3 possible ways to use a class as key. Nonetheless I have to admit that I think using the `operator<` approach is a bit cleaner.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Google's style guide is purposely restrictive for their own internal political reasons. Google's style guide does not allow for idiomatic C++ code. You should not, in general, code using Google's C++ style guide unless you work for Google.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy I don't mean to be harsh. The issue is that a code reviewer would be startled. Let me give you a new perspective: You see an `operator()` defined on a key type. Strange. What does this do? You can't tell from the class name. You can't tell by looking at the header file. You go into the implementation file and you find that it does a comparison. But why? Then you poke around the code to see where this class is used and only then do you find that this class is both a key and a comparator. You can see how this is confusing and unclear to those reading your code (reviewers)

Comment: @JordanMelo Yes, valid reasoning, that's why I already admitted that `operator<` is the cleaner solution. Harsh was perhaps the wrong word, I was referring to a StackOverflow user that immediately responds with `this is bad` because he / she does things in a different way.